# AngularJS: Promises & conditions based on results

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-resource

I have a complex promise chain, with each of the success handlers in then making some more API calls and passing on the results to the next then and so on.

I've come to a situation where, based on a condition, I may choose to stop the chain.

So, in a nutshell, my code looks like;

```
API.callGeneric(/* some params here */)
    .$promise
    .then(success(res) {
        if (processFurther(res)) {
            return API.callGeneric(res).$promise;
        } else {
            return someFunction(res); // so that the stuff inside the next successhandler still happens
        }
    }, failHandler)
    .then(success(res) {
        // do some stuff with res
        // do some important stuff independent of res (announce app ready, etc.)
    }, failHandler)
```

So, there is some stuff that needs to happen in the last step irrespective of whether or not I choose to return the promise from another API call or just an object.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue with the help of [@BenjaminGruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum).

So, basically, I needed the successHandler of the last .then to execute in any case – at least the part of it that didn't depend on the promise passed on from earlier in the chain.

What solves this is using `.finally`, but there's a catch. `.finally` executes irrespective of where you decide to reject the promise and break the chain. And in my scenario, that wasn't what I needed. In `.finally`, I needed to announce that my webapp was ready (through a websocket) to the server and other clients. But that would not be ideal if the first API call itself had to be rejected.

What solved it was maintaining a measure of the progress through the promise chain, so that my handler in `finally` was completely aware of how much progress had been made. If this was above a certain limit for my app to be declared ready, I ignored the last promise rejection.

So basically, the solution now looks like this;

```
var progress = 0;
API.callGeneric(/* some params */).$promise

    .then(successOne(res) {
        progress++;
        return API.callGeneric(res).$promise;
    }, handleErr)

    .then(successTwo(res) {
        progress++;
        if (isResPositive(res)) {
            return API.callGeneric(res).$promise;
        } else {
            var def = $q.defer();
            def.reject(res);
            return def.promise;
        }
    }, handleErr)

    .then(/* similar stuff */)

    /* etc */

    .finally(function () {
        if (progress > limit) {
            // do stuff here
        } else {
            // failure, don't do stuff
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reject promise like `$q.reject(reason)` as a return value for function.

```
.then(function () { 
   return $q.reject() 
}).then(function () {
  console.log('never happens'); 
}).catch(function () { 
  console.log('you are going here because of the reject above'); 
}).finally(function () {
  console.log('always happens');
});
```

Look at [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) for more info.

Comment: This is like stopping synchronous code execution by throwing an exception. Using rejections for normal flow control usually isn't a good idea. The important thing in your answer is the `.finally`.

Comment: @haneev I think I wasn't clear enough. The last .then has a successhandler and an errorhandler. The second last then is when I decide to call the api again and pass on the promise from it, or just pass a modified form of the previous result. In either case, I don't want to hit the next `then`'s error handler, I want to still pass on the information to the successhandler and get some stuff done.

Comment: @Ashesh can you write down how would your code look if all API calls you made were completely synchronous (return immediately) using synchronous flow control?

Comment: In particular, what if the call to `callGeneric` fails the second time?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum wow, thanks for that hint! I had completely misssed thinking about `.finally`, and it solved the problem.

Comment: @Ashesh when working with promises one of the great tools is to write how you would write your code if it was completely synchronous. I encourage you to write your own answer to this answer (and be sure to attach the synchronous version for the analogy). Hopefully, your version does not use rejections for flow control.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please add that as an answer, I'll accept, +1 it.

Comment: @Ashesh You're the one that ended up solving it so you should write the answer :) It would be beneficial if you write the steps that led you to solving the problem as it'll help future visitors with the same issue.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's usually how I approach these problems. I had completely overlooked that `.finally` exists.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've added the answer.